# jQuery .focus() only fires on first focus

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I have a jQuery event set up on an inputbox like so:

```
$("#myinput").focus((event)=>{console.log("Focused")});
```

but this only works once. I click into the input and it fires, then click out and back in again and it doesn't fire.

```
 $("#dataTable_filter > label > input[type='search']").focus((e) => {
            console.log("FOCUSED");


        });
```

Comment: Your code works, check your HTML and make sure you call jQquery before the code is running. If you are still having problem share your HTML here

Comment: If it works once, then there is no problem in the HTML Code.

Comment: Code is there now